# Why does `instance.constructor.staticProperty` in TypeScript not work?

Tags: javascript, typescript

The following does not work:

```
abstract class Foo {
  static get foo() { return 123 }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
  static get foo() { return 456 }
}

let b = new Bar

console.log(b.constructor.foo) // ERROR: Property 'foo' does not exist on type 'Function'.
```

([playground link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=abstract%20class%20Foo%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20static%20get%20foo()%20%7B%20return%20123%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aclass%20Bar%20extends%20Foo%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20static%20get%20foo()%20%7B%20return%20456%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Alet%20b%20%3D%20new%20Bar%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log(b.constructor.foo)%20%2F%2F%20ERROR%3A%20Property%20'foo'%20does%20not%20exist%20on%20type%20'Function'.%0D%0A))

Why does it not work? Why isn't it smart enough to know the type there? How do I do it without referencing the `Bar` class directly?

I want to use the form `b.constructor`, because I may not know which subclass will be used for the instance:

```
// ...continuing from before...

class Baz extends Foo {
  static get foo() { return 42 }
}

class Lorem extends Foo {
  static get foo() { return 3.14 }
}

function readStaticFoo(obj: Foo) {
  console.log(obj.constructor.foo) // ERROR: Property 'foo' does not exist on type 'Function'.
}

const baz = new Baz
const lor = new Lorem

readStaticFoo(baz)
readStaticFoo(lor)
```

([playground link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=abstract%20class%20Foo%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20static%20get%20foo()%20%7B%20return%20123%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aclass%20Bar%20extends%20Foo%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20static%20get%20foo()%20%7B%20return%20456%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Alet%20b%20%3D%20new%20Bar%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log(b.constructor.foo)%20%2F%2F%20ERROR%3A%20Property%20'foo'%20does%20not%20exist%20on%20type%20'Function'.%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Baz%20extends%20Foo%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20static%20get%20foo()%20%7B%20return%2042%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Lorem%20extends%20Foo%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20static%20get%20foo()%20%7B%20return%203.14%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20readStaticFoo(obj%3A%20Foo)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20console.log(obj.constructor.foo)%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20baz%20%3D%20new%20Baz%0D%0Aconst%20lor%20%3D%20new%20Lorem%0D%0A%0D%0AreadStaticFoo(b)%0D%0AreadStaticFoo(baz)%0D%0AreadStaticFoo(lor)%0D%0A))

I've worked around the problem with this hack:

```
function readStaticFoo(obj: Foo) {
  const foo = (obj.constructor as typeof Foo).foo
  console.log(foo)
}
```

([playground link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=abstract%20class%20Foo%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20static%20get%20foo()%20%7B%20return%20123%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aclass%20Bar%20extends%20Foo%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20static%20get%20foo()%20%7B%20return%20456%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Alet%20b%20%3D%20new%20Bar%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log(b.constructor.foo)%20%2F%2F%20ERROR%3A%20Property%20'foo'%20does%20not%20exist%20on%20type%20'Function'.%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Baz%20extends%20Foo%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20static%20get%20foo()%20%7B%20return%2042%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Lorem%20extends%20Foo%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20static%20get%20foo()%20%7B%20return%203.14%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20readStaticFoo(obj%3A%20Foo)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20const%20foo%20%3D%20(obj.constructor%20as%20typeof%20Foo).foo%0D%0A%20%20console.log(foo)%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20baz%20%3D%20new%20Baz%0D%0Aconst%20lor%20%3D%20new%20Lorem%0D%0A%0D%0AreadStaticFoo(b)%0D%0AreadStaticFoo(baz)%0D%0AreadStaticFoo(lor)%0D%0A))

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it is a [much wanted feature that TS devs are okay to add, but haven't gotten around to it yet](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3841).